# Switch between fingerprint and password sign in options in windows 8

Tags: login, windows-8

In windows 8 I noticed the following on my laptop:

When I am on the lock/login screen I can swipe my finger at any time and it will allow me to pass the screen. This is quite convenient.

However, when I last used my laptop fingerprint scanner, and am now working with an external screen and keyboard, things are not so nice. I can basically choose one of these 2 options:

1. Click on sign-in options, then click on password
2. Open the lid of my laptop, and swipe my finger anyway

Notably, this is NOT an option:

3. Start typing my password directly

Now I have the following question:

### Why is it so hard to switch from fingerprint sign on to password sign on in the windows 8 login screen?

Comment: I suspect you will need to speak to the designers who came up with this experience to get an answer to your question (the contributors here are unlikely to know the answer). I agree it looks like everything has not been thought through thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Windows 7 and 10, and in both there was an option to disable biometric login by going to Control Panel -> Hardware and Sound -> Biometric Devices. Here left-click on the device and select disable.

By Disabling this, you will directly be asked for password. Maybe you can try the same for Windows 8